# What is the best way to represent a (Now Hiring) link or icon in a webpage

Tags: icons, hyperlinks

What is the best way to represent a (Now Hiring) link or icon in a webpage.
some webpages locate it into a footer or something very bottom of the page.
some is suggesting to put it in the very top of the page beside the menu or in somewhere in the header, specially when there is some vacancies.

for me I don't think it is so important to put in in the same level and weight of my header. what do you think?

==== updated ====

sorry not mentioning the main function of the firm that I did a webpage for. It's a Cultural center ... a Library and Art center and museums, And we are not usually offering jobs.

Comment: can you provide an image/mockup of the web?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend what the main purpose of your site is, and are your users of the product the type of people you are looking to hire?

If you are a web design blog, looking to hire web designers then I would give it more importance (up at the top, big and bold, multiple locations throughout the site).

An example would be Metalab who are an agency, and finding talent is important to their business (also the people visiting their site are probably qualified for the role). The have careers in the main navigation at the top of the site:

[image: MetaLab Header]

But if you are a glasses retailer and looking to hire a sys admin, I wouldn't give it such importance since most your users won't be interested that you are hiring.

Most retailers (who are hiring in in stores and head office jobs) seem to have links in the footer:

---

[image: River Island Careers]

[image: Office Careers]

[image: Schuh Careers]

Comment: sorry not mentioning the main function of the firm that I did a webpage for. It's a Cultural center ... a Library and Art center and museums.of course if I am a steward so my webpage will be all about jobs and vacancies.. but if I am a cultural center it would be more different, specially we are not usually offering jobs. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

All are suitable ways however if your highering in the engineering community or where english may not be someones first language maybe some sort of visual representations could help non native english speakers especially if its slipped in.

**Heres some results i liked when I googled hiring icons**

[image]

really great no words to get confused here

[image]

also a fan of this one

[image]

not as great because the focus is the wording but i like the head and Tie icon maybe different colors would make it pop more

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bob Sinclar  for your answer ... But I am asking for its location in the webpage not for visual representation.

Comment: Whoops Sorry about that